# Update statement in SQL when two different search items present

Tags: sql-update

I've got a small issue when updating a column. When a db needs restored on a testdb, I need to change some fields in order to prevent issues on the production db.

Most of the time it only is adjusting the e-mail address and web address.

Now I walked on this one:
In a table there is a column filled with URL's. One URL starts with `fairworks...` and the other starts with `www.fairworks...`

Both URL need to be changed to: `Test.fairworks...`

So `fairw.....` and `www.fairw...` need to be changed to: `TEST.fairw...`

I tried to update with this code but somehow it doesn't do what I intended

Update URL

```
SET Url = CASE 
      WHEN (LEFT(Url,3) = 'fai' THEN REPLACE(Url,'fair','test.fair') 
      ELSE 
      WHEN (LEFT(Url,6) = 'www.fa THEN REPLACE(Url,'www.fair', 'test.fair') 
      END
```

I can't see where I go wrong.

Because I haven't enough points I cannot add the complete code. Both URL starts with HTTP://

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? But the `ELSE` is completely wrong. Remove that.

Comment: I work on SQL2012. You're right. The else isn't good in here.

Comment: SQL is a query language, not a DBMS product. And there is no SQL 2012 standard. There is a SQL2011 standard (which is the current) and there was SQL2008 before that.

Comment: I removed the Else and with a little trial made it better. It worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you could use something like this:

```
UPDATE [YourTable]
SET Url = 'www.fairworks' + SUBSTRING(Url, 4, LEN(Url)-4)
WHERE LEFT(Url,4) = 'fair' 

UPDATE [YourTable]
SET Url = 'www.fairworks' + SUBSTRING(Url, 8, LEN(Url)-8)
WHERE LEFT(Url,8) = 'www.fair'
```

By the way, you missed an apostrophe (just before `THEN`) in your code:

```
WHEN (LEFT(Url,6) = 'www.fa THEN REPLACE(Url,'www.fair', 'test.fair')
```

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks a lot. This is something I'm going to try. Nice for learning too.
I adjusted my CASE WHEN code with the remarks from user @– a_horse_with_no_name 
Also learned now how to play with the replace statement in a Update query.

 I also noticed the missing apostrophe. Always nice how SSMS shows missing characters ;0)
When adjusting my query I needed to place the apostrophe

Comment: This is my code now. I've tested it and it worked exactly as intended.

  UPDATE [table]
  SET  Url = CASE WHEN (LEFT(url,10)) = 'http://10.' THEN REPLACE(Url,'.17','.99')
     WHEN (LEFT(Url,10)) = 'http://fai' THEN REPLACE(Url,'http://fai', 'http://test.fai')
     WHEN (LEFT(Url,10)) = 'http://www' THEN REPLACE(Url,'http://www', 'http://test') END